# How to send URL back as reply by web server in python

Tags: python

I have written this HTTP web server in python which simply sends reply "Website Coming Soon!" to the browser/client, but I want that this web server should sends back the URL given by the client, like if I write

```
http://localhost:13555/ChessBoard_x16_y16.bmp
```

then server should reply back the same url instead of "Website Coming Soon!" message.
please tell how can I do this?

**Server Code:**

```
import sys
import http.server
from http.server import HTTPServer
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
#import usb.core

class MyHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler): #handles client requests (by me)

    #def init(self,req,client_addr,server):
     #   SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self,req,client_addr,server)      

    def do_GET(self):
        response="Website Coming Soon!"
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "application/json;charset=utf-8")
        self.send_header("Content-length", len(response))
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(response.encode("utf-8"))
        self.wfile.flush()
        print(response)


HandlerClass = MyHandler
Protocol     = "HTTP/1.1"
port = 13555
server_address = ('localhost', port)
HandlerClass.protocol_version = Protocol

try:
    httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, MyHandler)
    print ("Server Started")
    httpd.serve_forever()
except:
    print('Shutting down server due to some problems!')
    httpd.socket.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you're asking, sort of, but it's a little complicated.

When a client (e.g., a web browser) connects to your web server, it sends a request that look like this:

```
GET /ChessBoard_x16_y16.bmp HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:13555
```

This assumes your client is using HTTP/1.1, which is likely true of anything you'll find these days.  If you expect HTTP/1.0 or earlier clients, life is much more difficult because there is no `Host:` header.

Using the value of the `Host` header and the path passed as an argument to the `GET` request, you can construct a URL that in many cases will match the URL the client was using.

But it won't necessarily match in all cases:

- There may be a proxy in between the client and your server, in which case both the path and hostname/port seen by your code may be different from that used by the client.
- There may be packet manipulation rules in place that modify the destination ip address and/or port, so that the connection seen by your code does not match the parameters used by the client.

In your `do_GET` method, you can access request headers via the
`self.headers` attribute and the request path via `self.path`.  For example:

```
def do_GET(self):
    response='http://%s/%s' % (self.headers['host'],
                        self.path)
```